# Regex Persian Date validation

Tags: regex, string, validation, date, nsregularexpression

I want a **Regular Expression** for validation Persian date like `1396/4/3`, `1396/12/08` or something else. 

in other words, I want to ensure that format of Persian Date (as `String`) is some thing like these valid formats are:

1.`YYYY/MM/DD`

2.`YYYY/MM/D`

3.`YYYY/M/DD`

4.`YYYY/M/D`

any Solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this **Regex** :

> `/^[1-4]\d{3}\/((0[1-6]\/((3[0-1])|([1-2][0-9])|(0[1-9])))|((1[0-2]|(0[7-9]))\/(30|([1-2][0-9])|(0[1-9]))))$/`

this regex in jquery full check your persian date template

**Year** : 4 digits starts with 1300 or 1400

**Month,Day** : for the 6 first months of a year calculate 31 days and for the 5 next months of a year calculate 30 days and for last month of a year calculate 29 days

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long but it works everywhere (for example in `grep -E` in **bash**):

```
^[1][1-4][0-9]{2}\/((0[1-6]\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(0[7-9]\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(1[0-1]\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(12\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])))
```

the format is: YYYY/MM/DD

from year 1100 to 1499

and **Esfand** is 29 days in this expression.

Answer (score 2):

use this **regex**:

```
^(\\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

with this regex:

- **Year** is 4 digits.
- **Month** is smaller than equal 12
- **Day** is smaller than equal 31

Comment: how nice, you ask and answer on same time.

Comment: @ecko, I use `Q&A-style` of stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: How do you want to validate by regexp if for example the leap day Esfand 30 is valid or not? And some months never have 31 days so your suggested regexp-based answer is not sufficient.

Comment: @meno-hochschild Regex don't exempt you from coding, a Persian Calendar library may satisfies all requirements that you mentioned, But Regex is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern. Sophisticated thinking makes problem more complex. In other words, this Regex can be a part of a library.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this:

```
^1[34][0-9][0-9]\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

It supports:

**Year:** 1300-1499

**Month:** 1-12 and 01-12

**Day:** 1-31 and 01-31

Answer (score 0):

I edit @MortezaAsadi 's answer to this:

```
^(\d{4})\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this
**^(1[3-4][0-9][0-9])//$**

to include
1300/01/01 .. 1499/12/31

and these also give errors

1200/01/01 .. 1400/13/01 .. 1400/12/32

Answer (score 0):

`1[3-4]\d\d\/(1[0-2]|[1-9]|0[1-9])\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9])($)`

year: 1300-1499

month: 1-12 or 01-12

day: 1-31 or 01-31

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple regex for validating the Jalaali date.

The year starts with 13 or 14.

```
^1[3-4]\d{2}((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))$
```